# How can you pass a Boolean statement into a function as an argument?

Tags: python

I was looking into the very well known Python SQLite ORM SQLalchemy, and noticed how when you are querying the database, to pass arguments, you do something like this:

```
query = Student.select().where(db.and_(Student.columns.Major == 'English', Student.columns.Pass != True))
output = conn.execute(query)
print(output.fetchall())
```

Notice this part being passed as an argument:

```
(db.and_(Student.columns.Major == 'English', Student.columns.Pass != True)
```

If I enter something like that into a function, I get Boolean values that are return i.e. True, False.

I was wondering how they are able to not get Boolean values passed through?

I think it might have something to do with the `__eq__` dunder method but I'm still not sure how to implement it.

Comment: `Student.columns.Major == 'English'` invokes `Student.columns.Major.__eq__('English')`, which can return whatever it wants (e.g. a predicate function that, given a particular student instance, will return whether or not its major is English). It doesn't have to be a boolean.

Comment: Thanks, but also is there a separate dunder for greater than or equal to or not equal.

Comment: [Comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__), yes.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone wondering in the future how this is done. As @jonrsharpe stated, you use the python comparison magic methods.

```
object.__lt__(self, other) # x<y
object.__le__(self, other) # x<=y
object.__eq__(self, other) # x==y
object.__ne__(self, other) # x!=y
object.__gt__(self, other) # x>y
object.__ge__(self, other) # x>=y
```

You can return whatever you want from these magic methods, even though it's designed to only return Boolean values. So in SQLalchemy, they return I assume something like `WHERE name = 'Bob' AND age = '29'`, then the function can use that to create the actual command to be executed in the SQLite database.